# CSS ms-grid equivalent in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, canvas, css-grid

I am trying to use this in Windows app and Chrome web browser, but the web browser does not show the `canvasButtons` div. I want the `canvasButtons` to show up below the `#canvasDiv`. The `overflow:hidden` property causes it to not show up. But it works fine as windows app. Is there any equivalent of ms-grid ?

```
.container {
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr auto;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.canvasEle {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.canvasButtons {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;     
    display: flex;  
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center; 
}
```

```
 <div style="overflow:hidden">   
        <div class="container">
            <div id="canvasDiv">
               <canvas width="510" height="370" class="canvasEle"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="canvasButtons" >

                   <div class="button" onClick= handler()>
                        ....
                   </div>

                   <div class="button" onClick = handler()>

                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flyouts" >.....</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using `display: flex` for the `canvasButtons` section, but even that didnt work well. The `canvasButtons` div got aligned as I wanted, but the click handlers weren't working later.

Comment: The more concise way to state the problem is - 
<div style="overflow:hidden">
<div id="container" style= "display:flex; flex-direction: column" height = 100 width = 100>
     <div id="canvas" height = 100 width = 100>
       .....
     </div>
     <div id="controls ">
       .....
     </div>
</div>
</div>

I cannot see the controls div until I remove overflow hidden property. How can I make it show up even if overflow is hidden. Is there a way I can shrink the canvas , so that both fit in?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to make the add teh following to teh controls div - bottom: 0px, position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an answer to the actual question ("Is there an equivalent of `-ms-grid` etc): yes—sort of. The latest version of the [Grid Layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) is implemented in Blink/Chrome Canary (December 2015) behind the "Experimental web platform features"-flag, in WebKit nightly builds, and in preview builds of Firefox (Developer edition etc).

Note that the prefixed version in IE10+ and Edge is based on an older spec, with similar basic functionality—for example, the layout in your question would work same, sans the `-ms`-prefix—but the new spec has lots more functionality.

It's likely that it will be released in all the above browsers during 2016, as long as nothing big happens with the spec.